# Consistency of `element.style.width` across browsers

Tags: javascript, css, cross-browser

If I have some [HTML](http://jsfiddle.net/YanickRochon/Le2JW/)

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="foo" style="width:75%;">Bar!</div>
</div>
```

and if I write this JavaScript (assuming jQuery for the benefit of the question)

```
alert( $("#container .foo")[0].style.width );
```

it should alert "75%". Will this output be consistent in *every* "modern" browsers? If not, what are the most popular non-standard browsers (even IE) that will fail to return the correct value?

#### ** Edit **

PLEASE! There are only two statements with question marks... THOSE are the questions!

Now, let me add something that may help *not* mislead the answers...

1. I know `element.style` is available across all browsers.
2. I know `element.style.width` is also available.
3. Using jQuery 1.3.2, calling `$("#container .foo").css('width')` does return `"75%"` **which is not true since at least version 1.6.4** (we're even beyond that major release too); the most recent jQuery version always output the width in pixels now.

So, considering the given HTML, will getting the element's `style.width` always return the true, declared size (ie. in percentage) across all browsers, or is there any rogue, non-standard one that will return a computed width in pixels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is supported in all major browsers. As seem [**here**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_width.asp) with some notes for old IE versions.

[**Here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Properties_Reference) you can found all available properties in this version of the `DOM` API.

**EDIT**

About the consistence of the value returned across browsers... that's depends on you, since it  returns **only** what's attributed via this API: if you use `%`, you'll get `%`; if you use `em` you'll get `em` and so on.

It couldn't make sense by other way. Let's say that you apply a 70% width in your element and, hypothetically, the engine uses only pixel values under the hood. So it will convert the value internally to 70% of the pixels count of the parent's width. Once your parent's width is changed the value stored in pixels gone forever, it will be evaluated in another percentage value.

**tl;dr - It only makes sense to be stored as is, so what you give is what you get.**

I'm pretty sure about this behavior. But just to make sure, I confirmed this behavior on earlier versions of Chrome, Firefox, Opera and IE 8+. So, remain in peace buddy and enjoy this feature.